# How do I get the value month of Datetimeoffset?

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I have a list of data that have datetimeoffset? as a column inside. I want to get specific data that has the month I want but don't know how. Below are those code I have tried.

This return me with error of `No overload for method 'Tostring'` which is weird since I can pass datetimeoffset? and use it in other function but if I do it directly inside where I get it, I can't use it.

```
      int d = DateTime.Now.Month;
      string f = d.ToString();
      var s = _dbContext.Documents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplyDate.ToString("MM") == f);
      return Json(s);
```

This return null

```
      int d = DateTime.Now.Month;
      string f = d.ToString();
      var s = _dbContext.Documents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplyDate.Value.ToString("MM") == f);
      return Json(s);
```

Comment: [DateTimeOffset.Month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.month?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Comment: This is Datetimeoffset? like ? is a part of it. I can't call .Month

Comment: `DateTimeOffset dt = new DateTimeOffset();
   var a = dt.Month;
  var b = dt.ToString("MM");`

what is `ApplyDate`?

Comment: DateTimeOffset?.Value.Month

Comment: @styx Applydate is the name of my column in database. It has Datetimeoffset? data type.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels Thank you sir. If you answer it below, I would give you the tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the month of a nullable datetimeoffset like this:

```
DateTimeOffset? dt;
dt?.Value.Month;
```

However, I really wonder if EF will be able to translate this:

```
x => x.ApplyDate?.Month == f
```

into a SQL expression.   I presume that it will fallback to in-memory filtering.
Next to that, even if EF is able to translate this into a SQL expression, it won't be optimal as indexes that might be defined on that column will not be used.

Therefore, I'd suggest to rewrite your LINQ expression to something like this:

```
x :> x.ApplyDate != null && x.ApplyDate >= new DateTimeOffset(someDate.Year, someDate.Month, 1) && x.ApplyDate <= new DateTimeOffset(someDate.Year, someDate.Month, daysInMonth)
```

(Given you want to retrieve the data that belong to a specific month in a specific year.  If you want to retrieve records that belong to a certain month, regardless the year, I see no other option)

Comment: Thank you, sir. All I have to do is replace ToString with Month which make it like this "ApplyDate.Value.Month" and it's work.

Comment: please consider that `.?` only available from c#6.0

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeOffset?` is `Nullable` type therefore is has no overload of `ToString(string format)` like  `DateTimeOffset` has.

to get get the month value from your `DateTimeOffset?` you can

1. `x.ApplyDate.Value.ToString("MM"`)
2. `x.ApplyDate.Value.Month`

please consider that you might want to check if `ApplyDate.Value`  is null **before** obtaining  its Month property

Answer (score 0):

Your code above shows DateTime, not DateTimeOffSet.

DateTimeOffSet is Struct, and if you have a **nullable** value, you need to check the value first and then **get the month from the value part**

```
DateTimeOffSet myNullableDateTime = someValue...//
```

---

Option 1:

```
// notice I added value below

myNullableDateTime.HasValue? "?Month="+myNullableDateTime.EscapeDataString(myNullableDateTime.Value.ToString()):"")
```

---

Option 2:

```
if(myNullableDateTime.HasValue)
 {
    var Month = myNullableDateTime.Month
    TimeSpan difference = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(myNullableDateTime.Value);
    // convert the difference to what you need and get Month 
 }
```

I have not compiled it, but it should get you the answer or pretty close.